# Initialize on first access

Tags: crystal-lang

I have the following accessor method:

```
def self.database : DB::Database
  if @@database.nil?
    config = Utils.config["database"].as(Hash)
    connection = [
      "postgres://#{config["user"]}:#{config["password"]}",
      "@localhost/stats",
    ].join

    @@database = DB.open connection
  else
    @@database
  end
end
```

which is guaranteed to return a `DB::Database`. I am not sure how to declare the class variable:

```
class Daemon
  @@database

  def self.database : DB::Database
  end
end
```

I am presented with a few options by the compiler, but most options don't yield suggestions which compile:

- `@@database = uninitialized DB::Database` compiles, but does not pass the `nil?` test as discussed [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4544).
- There is no way for me to instantiate a placeholder `DB::Database` easily.
- I'm also not sure how to initialize using the accessor function `self.database`, although that would work and give the type guarantees.

How can properly initialize the class variable? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

This solution works:

```
class Daemon
  @@database = uninitialized DB::Database

  def self.database : DB::Database
    config = Utils.config["database"].as(Hash)
    connection = [
      "postgres://#{config["user"]}:#{config["password"]}",
      "@localhost/stats",
    ].join

    DB.open connection
  end
```

The only problem with writing the class assessor this way is that I would start leaking file descriptors — each time I access `@@database`, I open a new connection to the database. I want to initialize `@@database` only during the first access and figure out a way to make the compiler happy with it starting out `uninitialized`.

Even more annoying:

```
class Daemon
  @@database = uninitialized DB::Database
  @@database_init = false

  def self.database : DB::Database
    if !@@database_init
      config = Utils.config["database"].as(Hash)
      connection = [
        "postgres://#{config["user"]}:#{config["password"]}",
        "@localhost/stats",
      ].join

      @@database = DB.open connection
      @@database_init = true
    end

    @@database
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a class var nillable and conditionally assign a value in a class method:

```
class Daemon
  @@database : DB::Database?

  def self.database
    @@database ||= begin
      config = Utils.config["database"].as(Hash)
      connection = [
        "postgres://#{config["user"]}:#{config["password"]}",
        "@localhost/stats",
      ].join

      DB.open connection
    end
  end
end

Daemon.database.query "..." # => #<PG::ResultSet:0x103ea2b40 ...>
```

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to `class_getter database do ... end`.

Comment: I'm still unsure about the class variable declaration. If I omit it entirely, the compiler complains `Can't infer the type of class variable '@@database' of Daemon`. If I leave it `uninitialized`, I get a segfault. I've updated my post.

Comment: @JamesTaylor sorry, my fault. Updated the answer

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!